# Handling Null values in a HashMap

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashmap

I have the following HashMap  which returns Studentlist,Booklist and Subjectlist.

```
Map<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        ResultSet rs1 = (ResultSet) storedProcedureCall.getObject(4);
        ResultSet rs2 = (ResultSet) storedProcedureCall.getObject(5);
        ResultSet rs3 = (ResultSet) storedProcedureCall.getObject(6);

        List<Object> studIds = getStudentIds("studentID", rs1);
        List<book> bookList = getBookList("books", rs2);
        List<book> bookSubjects = getBookSubjects("subjects", rs3);

        resultMap.put("studList", studIds);
        resultMap.put("bookList", bookList);
        resultMap.put("subjList", bookSubjects);


        if (resultMap.isEmpty()) {
            return Optional.empty();
        } else {
            return Optional.of(resultMap);
        }
```

How can i handle null values for studlist,booklist,subjlist. Currently am depending on isEmpty() but still am getting NullpointerException when null values comes. Since i couldnt find isNull() in java, how can i handle this exception.

Comment: Why not something as simple as an if check: `if (xxx == null) {...}`?

Comment: Why do you use a Map<String, Object> to store three lists, instead of an object with three fields, having the appropriate types? And why return an Optional instead of simply returning the map (which can never be empty, since you always add three entries to it)? And why not respect  Java naming conventions?

Comment: Think about it. If the map is itself null, how can you call a function on a null object? You will have to use resultMap == null to verify.

Comment: Null values are perfectly valid in maps, so isEmpty is not gonna help. You do not show the code that ultimately consumes the map, but in situations like this, I often find it better to make methods getStudentIds, getBookList and getBookSubjects return empty lists instead of null. Consumer code will usually iterate over the list anyway, so iterating over an empty list will have the same effect of doing nothing at all, without all the pains of checking for null.